# Animated apocalyptic sci-fi movie from the 70's or early 80's

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

Every few years I make an attempt to find information about this barely-remembered show that I saw.  I was probably around 6 years old, and lived in South Africa at the time, for what that helps.

There were two protagonists, one of whom was a scientist or technologist of some format.  They were discussing how to save the (city / world? ) from a black, formless orb which had appeared in their city.  The views they showed of this orb against the city backdrop were all pink / purple, so dawn / evening / apocalyptic colour scheme.  At one point, a laser (if I recall) is fired at the orb, which absorbs the attack and grows in size (much like the evil planet does in 5th Element).  The impression I remember is that this was one of the last things they could try, and that they were growing desperate.

I believe it was in english, and is probably from the same era as Harmony Gold's english dubs of Robotech.  That said, with the state of South Africa's TV networks and our international isolation at the time I have no idea whether my impressions are accurate.

I'm Curious if anyone has any idea what this movie or series might have been.

Comment: The orb suggests Heavy Metal and the Loc-Nar, but that's a WAG.

Comment: It also reminds me a little bit of Akira.

Comment: Any memories of the drawing style? Was it anime perhaps?

Comment: @poepje it wasn't anime - or at least, not classic anime.  I remember the people in it looking more 'human' than in, for e.g Robotech.

Comment: On what year approximately did you see this ?

Comment: @user27221 hard to estimate, I'd say probably somewhere between 1984 and 1986

Answer (score 3):

Possibly [Wicked City (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098692/?ref_=nv_sr_2) ?

> There is Earth, our familiar world, and then there is the Black World, a parallel dimension that very few people are aware of. For centuries, a pact between the two worlds has been observed to maintain peace, and terms must be negotiated and renewed soon to continue relative harmony. This time around, there is a militant faction called The Radicals that will stop at nothing to prevent the signing of a new treaty for inter-dimensional peace.

In the trailer you see the city backdrop with all the colors mentioned. There is a two man team trying to solve the issue. Although there doesn't appear to be a *literal* black orb (or world). There is the extra-dimension sister world *called* Black World.